# Add headers from csv to dictionary keys and the columns below them as a list of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have the following csv file:

```
h1  h2  h3  h4
10  11  12  13
14  15  16  17
18  19  20  21
```

And the output that I'd like to obtain is a dictionary:

```
dict = {'h1': ['10','14','18'], 'h2': ['11','15','19'], 
        'h3': ['12','16','20'], 'h4': ['13','17','21']}
```

I have tried the following but I didn't get exactly what I need:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

def get_columns_from_source_file():
    source_file_reader = csv.DictReader(open('custom_delimited_file'))
    columns_storage = defaultdict(list)

    for source_file_row in source_file_reader:
        for source_file_column, source_file_value in source_file_row.items():
            columns_storage.setdefault(source_file_column, []).append(source_file_value)

    return columns_storage


print(get_columns_from_source_file())
```

What I get is:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'h1\th2\th3\th4': ['10\t11\t12\t13', '14\t15\t16\t17', '18\t19\t20\t21']})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to add the `delimiter='\t'` argument and you'll get what you want:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

def get_columns_from_source_file():
    source_file_reader = csv.DictReader(open('test.csv'), delimiter='\t')
    columns_storage = defaultdict(list)

    for source_file_row in source_file_reader:
        for source_file_column, source_file_value in source_file_row.items():
            columns_storage.setdefault(source_file_column, []).append(source_file_value)

    return columns_storage


print(get_columns_from_source_file())
```

#### Result:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'h1': ['10', '14', '18'], 'h2': ['11', '15', '19'], 'h3': ['12', '16', '20'], 'h4': ['13', '17', '21']})
```